# Мне 14, хочу стать Web разработчиком. Что мне для этого делать?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, css3, html5

Мне 14 лет, перехожу в 9 класс. В будущем хочу связать свою жизнь с Web-программированием, пока что я знаю на достаточно хорошем уровне Python. html 5 и CSS 3 прохожу в html academy и могу сверстать простенький сайт , только начал изучать javascript. Я думаю пока рано говорить в какую именно сферу: фронтент или бэкэнл, но и то, и то планирую освоить. Подскажите пожалуйста, что изучать, какие использовать материалы. К чему мне готовиться?

Comment: Сорри за офтоп) красавчик конечно, что уже задумываешься о том что учить, но я бы тебе советовал в твои годы не о том думать)

Comment: Не ограничивайте себя веб-разработкой. Вы молоды, у вас высокие когнитивные способности, самое время осваивать профессию как можно шире. Во-первых, конечно, углубляйте имеющиеся знания, смотрите на фрейморки. В Python это Django, я думаю, вы на нём и пишете. Смотрите, что есть в JS. Посмотрите на низкий уровень: C, Rust, Go. Посмотрите на ООП: Java, Kotlin, C#. Попробуйте функциональные языки. F#, Scala, Haskell.

Comment: Математику) ЯП и цели со временем могут измениться, а математика где-то, да пригодится)

Comment: Для начала читать правила на ресурсах вроде этого) Если это твое, сам поймешь что учить — то что интересно.

Comment: английский нужен. лучше до разговорного уровня. очень много первоисточников на английском придётся читать.

Comment: То что хочешь, то и делай! Слушай маму, кушай кашу, учи английский, читай книжки, которые нравятся - будут вопрос по программированию - заходи )

Answer (score 1):

Python - это хорошо, никогда не помешает, и, если что можешь писать на нем бекэнд(на flask или django). Я тоже когда-то начанал CSS и HTML с html-academy, но этого портала, по моему мнению, не хватит. Могу посоветовать книгу "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5" [(Ссылка)](https://www.combook.ru/product/11896922/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_ez2BRCyARIsAJfg-ktfcXsFBmMX4ET7cjpRqHjvxrJ0vxon9QXixAOmpaXgDQqhaR-TyXUaAodVEALw_wcB). Сам по ней изучал основы "сайтостроения". По поводу JS: я изучаю его на всемилюбимом https://learn.javascript.ru/. Но перед ним надо, конечно же, знать основы html и css. Также могу посоветовать YT видеокурс от канала "Web Developer Blog" [Практика JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JISFx18J7nc&list=PLVfMKQXDAhGW0p_BEEe47UkCgNoS_dyki). Что даст еще больше знаний по-поводу фронтэнда.
Что по поводу БекЭнда, я здесь не силен, поэтому: знатоки в студию!